# Is this the correct way to set up Hudson to build from git

Tags: git, build, hudson, repository

I just installed Hudson in ubuntu 10.04, including the offical git plugin.  I installed git-core, and tried setting up git to build my HTPC disto, OpenELEC.tv.   I started it, and it says cloning git, but i don't see any status, and wondering if I set it up correctly?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your project fails to build. Have you looked at the output log of your builds, can you post this here?

Has everybody read access to your repository?

Comment: its not my repo,   and I made some changes to it.  I can now clone, but it finishes without building.   the command I'd enter from a command line to build is something like PROJECT=ION ARCH=x86_64 make release    i have not yet found an area to specify this command line build option.  I've tried using the parameters, as well as build step add shell command, but this doesn't work either.  Is there a way to specify the build command to use?

Comment: In the execute shell, simply write everything you would type in the normal shell to compile your project.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  had to create a shell script with my make command in it, and then run that.  Builds are running now, will see if they successfully complete.

Thanks!